# cannot access a page in a subdirectory of /var/www

Tags: apache-2.2, mediawiki

I have problem with accessing [mediawiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) on a server with apache2.
I installed mediawiki in /var/www/wiki directory.

I can access index.php in /var/www by typing in browser "myhostIP", but if I type
"myhostIP"/wiki then line became "different_name_of_myhost"/wiki/index.php/Main_Page and I have message "firefox cannot find server at "different_name_of_myhost"/wiki/index.php/Main_Page".

If I try just type in browser "different_name_of_myhost" then I cannot access
index.php at /var/www. why? and why I cannot access mediawiki?
If the problem was connected with access rights of /var/www/wiki then I would get "access denied" in the browser. Do you have clue what is going on? thanks

Comment: Usually this happens due to short URL misconfiguration. Check the manual. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message:

```
firefox cannot find server at "different_name_of_myhost"/wiki/index.php/Main_Page
```

indicates that this is a DNS problem. You need to make sure you access the URL using the IP address or using a resolvable name. This name should be defined in the DNS server you are using.

Alternatively, you need include the name-IP mapping in the hosts file of your machine. In this case, your machine only will be able to use this name,